# Excel 2016 - If statements with counting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to be able to count all items that start with a certain string of numbers (i.e 12345) and have Excel tell me how many items in the table start with those 5 numbers and how many don't.

The items actually contain 13 digits but only the first 5 matter.

Any ideas how I would pull that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"12345*")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is formatted as text, then you can use `COUNTIF(range, "12345*")` The * is a wildcard, and will 'match' any text (`?` is the single character wildcard).

Otherwise, you will need something more ... creative. The best option I'm finding is to use something like

```
COUNT(A:A)-COUNTIF(A:A,">=1234600000000")-COUNTIF(A:A,"<1234500000000")
```

#### Explanation

This counts the total, then removes anything smaller than `1234500000000` (which will start with `12344`) and finally removes anything larger than or equal to `1234600000000` (which start with `12346`). The downside to this approach is that your numbers must all be 13 digits: A 12 digit number starting with 12345 will not be counted.

#### Alternative

You can also use a VBA module function if you really want a nice, clean-looking formula. This will require a macro-enabled workbook (*.xlsm). (I'll leave more specifics to their own question)